# error when adding add_header to nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add "add_header" to nginx but the reload is failing:

**add_header**

```
add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD" always;
```

When I run nginx -t, it points to this line mentioning I am passing too many parameters.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**url for add_header:**

```
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header
```

Comment: You have old nginx. `always` was added in nginx 1.7.5

Comment: thanks - you can add as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an old nginx.

`always` flag was added in nginx 1.7.5